# Word 2019 VBA question, Duplicate hyperlink with format change and URL change on the duplicate

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi :) I'm quite new at Word.

I'm looking for a VBA way to go from this:

https://www.google.com

to

https://www.google.com  <sup>[Mirror](https://mirror.something.com/https://www.google.com)</sup>

The mirror part of the URL is fixed for every Hyperlink (https://mirror.something.com/)

This for each link in a Word document (including endnotes/footnotes) but excluding some Hyperlinks with a certain string in the address. Like for instance.

https://www.bing.com contains bing.com and should remain unmodified.

Could anyone enlighten me?

Thank you!!

Tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Stry As Range, h As Long, Rng As Range
Dim StrLnk As String, StrTxt As String
For Each Stry In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
  For h = Stry.Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
    StrLnk = Stry.Hyperlinks(h).Address
    StrTxt = LCase(Split(StrLnk, ".")(1))
    Select Case StrTxt
      Case "bing"
      Case "something": h = h - 1
      Case Else
        Set Rng = Stry.Hyperlinks(h).Range
        With Rng
          .Characters.Last.Next.InsertBefore " "
          .End = .End + 1
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
          .Hyperlinks.Add .Duplicate, "https://mirror.something.com/" & StrLnk, , , "Mirror"
          .End = .End + 1
          .End = .Fields(1).Result.End
          .Font.Superscript = True
        End With
    End Select
  Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

PS: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You should normally show that you've invested some coding effort of your own.

Comment: I'm sorry ... I apologize for this ... I did make quite some efforts but far from your answer. I tried much simpler methods. I tried your answer tho and it works on small documents but on large documents it throws an Error 9 out of range error and fails.

Comment: Before I could help further, I'd need to know what circumstances cause the code to fail. You need to have a look at the document and see what the circumstances are where the last hyperlink was updated and the one either side of that.

Comment: It failed at this Step: "StrTxt = LCase(Split(StrLnk, ".")(1))" After a link within a Table that was changed just fine. Just before an hyperlink that links within the document itself.  So specifically it failed at an Hyperlink of this type { HYPERLINK \I "Section:" }.

Comment: So I guess this is because in that specific Hyperlink, there is no "." delimiter right and this is why it's out of range?

Comment: Fixed myself by adding "If InStr(StrLnk, ".") > 0 Then" in statement. Thank you!

Comment: «So I guess this is because in that specific Hyperlink, there is no "." delimiter» Correct, the code was only written to handle hyperinks of the kind you described in your original post. Your implementation of the Instr test should resolve that.